# Can I make SAS work with a .sas7bdat file with a name more than 32 characters long?

Tags: sas

I've been provided with a .sas7bdat file with a file name that has 36 characters before the extension.  Aside from renaming the file, is there any way I can get SAS to work with it?  I tried `options validvarname=extend`, but I don't think that's the answer:

```
11         options validvarname=extend;
                ____________
                14
ERROR 14-12: Invalid option value extend for SAS option VALIDVARNAME.
```

I using SAS 9.3 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
VALIDVARNAME=V7 | UPCASE | ANY
```

is relevant for variable names, not dataset names.

While

```
options VALIDMEMNAME=EXTEND;
```

refers to datasets, but only allows special characters in the name, the limit is still 32characters.

from SAS Help:

```
> EXTEND
> specifies that a SAS data set name, a SAS data view name, or an item store name must follow these rules:
> Names can include national characters.
> The name can include special characters, except for the / \ * ? " < > |: -. characters.  
> Note: The SPD Engine does not allow ‘.’ (the period) anywhere in the member name.
> The name must contain at least one character.
> The length of the name can be up to 32 bytes.
> Null bytes are not allowed.
> Names cannot begin with a blank or a ‘.’ (the period).
```

So I think you have to rename the files.

Comment: In particular, `CAUTION:
Throughout SAS, using the name literal syntax with SAS member names that exceed the 32-byte limit or that have excessive embedded quotation marks might cause unexpected results.`